# A tex-script to impose multiple layout signatures (optionally saddle stitch) from pdf

Tags: layout, imposition

I am trying to add a pdf with 32 pages, A5 landscape to A3 landscape with a script.

[image: 32 page layout]

So far the pdftex or context have failed me and I wonder if I am missing something in there that might help me on my way?

My pdf-files are to heavy to upload here.

[image]

The code I've been running is:

```
\setuppapersize[A5,landscape][A3,landscape] %individual page A6 size, print size A3
\setuppaper[nx=4, ny=2] 
\setuparranging[2*4] %makes an 8 page gathering when folded (duplex printing!)
\setuplayout
  [backspace=0pt,
    topspace=0pt, %here I can add -1.5pt to make images overflow on centerfold pages but it will go on all pages
       width=middle,
      height=middle,
    location=middle,
      header=0pt,
      footer=0pt]
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\starttext

\insertpages
  [testpages_32.pdf][width=0pt]

\stoptext
```

Taken from https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition but it counts wrong, the last page should come before first page. Se the example.

Also I've tried PDF::Impose but that bugged out a lot and I made separate question about that and share that code there.
https://github.com/jamis/impose/issues/2

Comment: Welcome back to TeX.SE! I'm not really sure I understand your question. Do you want to collect multiple A5 pages from a pdf on an A3 page? Which LaTeX packages or code did you try to do this? Maybe you can make a small example document that adds the pages, and another small document that contains a single A5 page. It does not need to be your original document, as long as it allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Context is the one I am running now. Also tried pdftex. I will try to recreate with just numbers on the pages.

The last question here was for another project that was solved.

I have 32 X A5 landscapes that need to be imposed to A3 landscape (double sided) for cutting on the long side and then folded and saddle stitched.

Comment: Yes @KJO it's correct! I just wonder how to fix this the best way. I could do it manually but these are projects that I do quite often and they do not tend to be smaller or lesser. So I figured I rather find a solution for this pretty soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally here is visual signature to be followed.

[image]

So you need 8 A3 Flats (4 recto verso pairs)
Each pair follows the same cut and fold pattern
However the numbering needs to be spread.

Thus for the first sheet 1 and 32 are together (with 29 & 4 rotated above),
then 5 & 28 then 9 & 24 until finally
13 & 20 (with 16 & 17 rotated above, as shown)

You will need to slide flats around for your own duplex usage.
E.g you may want one set for 4 times one side then flip for obverse run of 4 flats OR
Duplex each sheet then stack for folding etc.

The Following is not a real usage it is just to show the rotation in action across multiple flats

[image]

I don't have physical A3 to test positioning but works as I expect in virtual PDF printer (or with slight adjustments works for 32 x A6L on A4L stock) or can be modified for portrait usage
Modular cut and paste to adjust parts easily including slit and fold stack order (Its correcting the page order of each signature set that's difficult) I found a really neat more complex 8 page TeX3 version but trying to change the maths up to cover permutations of 16 24 32 would need lots more templates so why not just this big TeX2 file which you can modify by trim down and save for smaller sets.

```
\documentclass[a3paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape, margin=0pt]{geometry}
\parindent=0pt
\lineskip=0pt
% this is a 32 x A5 Landscape page spread across 8 A3 Landscape flats
\newcommand{\filename}{testpages_32} %32 x A5s in sequence


\begin{document}%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\noindent\includegraphics[page=17,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=16,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}
  \includegraphics[page=20,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=13,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[page=15,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=18,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}
  \includegraphics[page=14,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=19,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[page=21,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=12,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}
  \includegraphics[page=24,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=9,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[page=11,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=22,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}
  \includegraphics[page=10,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=23,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[page=25,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=8,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}
  \includegraphics[page=28,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=5,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[page=7,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=26,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}
  \includegraphics[page=6,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=27,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[page=29,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=4,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}
  \includegraphics[page=32,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=1,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[page=3,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=30,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=180]{\filename}
  \includegraphics[page=2,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}%
  \includegraphics[page=31,width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight,angle=0]{\filename}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks exactly like I want it! I could work with portraits as well if that would be easier to code?

Comment: That PDF is an old project though. But hey! A looot of nice code to test! :D THANKS

Comment: This worked! It is not the dynamic solution I was looking for but at least I do not have to do it in InDesign or spend hundreds of dollars on software. <3